# Hovering black bar appears in browser on Facebook with Amazon Kindle Fire?

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, brave

Using Brave, Chrome, Bromite (so far), in Desktop mode on Amazon Kindle Fire tablet, a black horizontal bar routinely hovers and scrolls with the news feed, sort of "squishing" feed content making it such that only parts of posts are readily visible (see screenshots). Weirdly as if it were a line like a black hole and stuff is being squished around it like some bizarre user interface styled gravitational lensing.

[image]
Reminds me a little of the kind of visual anomaly you might see with a dying desktop video card, but this same phenomenon occurs on multiple such tablets running the latest firmware.

Upon logging out and logging back in things are fine for a few minutes, but then things start going haywire again. Searched, found no promising leads in this forum thus far.